# Travel with expired US visa

Tags: mexico, us-residents

I have a valid H1B, I-94, I-797C and an expired US visa (F1). Can I travel to Mexico for less than 30 days and come back?

Answer (score 2):

You can re-enter the US with Automatic Revalidation without needing to get a new US visa, since you have an unexpired I-94 and you are going to only Canada or Mexico for less than 30 days.

However, you will need to get a Mexican visa to visit Mexico. Holders of valid US visas can visit Mexico without a visa, but you no longer have a valid US visa.

Comment: *you will need to get a Mexican visa to visit Mexico* this may depend on the OP's nationality, it is possible that Mexico doesn't require a Visa for citizens of whatever country they are from